# New Google one-tap sign-up from extensions

Tags: google-identity

It looks like calling the `googleyolo` javascript object doesn't work with chrome extensions, probably because it's using an iframe with redirect under the hood, that extensions do not like.

Am I right in thinking chrome extensions are not supported? If yes, does anyone know if there is a plan to support them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s correct. Currently the API expects the calling page to not run inside an extension. We may change this in the future. However you can accomplish what you want to do via a chrome tab launch to a well known page which the extension can inject content scripts into, and notify via chrome cross tab messaging after sign in.